# Non-blocking concurrent message receive

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, d, nonblocking

Is there a standard function to receive messages concurrent, but non-blocking? It seems like all the functions available in `std.concurrency` are blocking and the closest I found to something that is non-blocking is `receiveTimeout` however it still waits until the timeout. I would like it to return immediately if there are no messages passed to the thread.

Here is what I came up with using `receiveTimeout`.

```
module main;

import std.concurrency;
import std.stdio : writefln, readln;
import core.time;
import core.thread;

void spawnedFunc() {
    while (true) {
        receiveTimeout(
            dur!("nsecs")(1),
            (int i) { writefln("Received %s", i); }
        );
        Thread.sleep(dur!("msecs")(100));
    }
}

void main() {
    auto tid = spawn(&spawnedFunc);
    while (true) {
        readln();
        send(tid, 42);
    }
}
```

**Update:**

Is my best bet a function like this?

```
void receiveNonBlocking(T...)(T ops) {
    receiveTimeout(
        dur!("nsecs")(1),
        ops
    );
}

...

receiveNonBlocking(
    (int i) { writefln("Received %s", i); }
);
```

Comment: Doesn't it work with `0.dur!"nsec"`?

Comment: Probably, but what I'm looking for is whether there's a standard way to do this and preferably one that does not involve the duration check.

Comment: Personally, I've also used `receiveTimeout (0.msecs);` as suggested above, and it did the job.

Comment: `if( period.isNegative || !m_putMsg.wait( period ) ) return false;` So, something like `nsecs(-1)` should be the best choice. Implementation of non blocking function wouldn't be much different from one with timeout. Just one more `if` check to execute before exit for function with negative timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at implementation of `receiveTimeout`:

```
if( period.isNegative || !m_putMsg.wait( period ) )
    return false;
```

So, providing negative timeout, e.g. `nsecs(-1)`, is the best choice here. And it wouldn't really impact performance, since implementation of non blocking function wouldn't be much different from current one with timeout. Just one more `if` check to execute before exit for function with negative timeout.