# Use a Queue to Communicate Between Threads in D

Tags: multithreading, d

It is easy enough in D to create a Queue type using the `std.container.dlist`.

I would like to have multiple threads but have them communicate with a queue, not with message passing (https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/multithreading/message-passing).  As I understand it the messages are designed to always receive data at particular points in the code; the receiving thread will block until the expected data is received.

(EDIT: I was informed about receiveTimeout but having a no timeout and just a check is really more appropriate in this case (maybe a timeout of 0?).  Also I am not sure what the message API will do if multiple messages are sent before any any are received.  I will have to play with that.)

```
void main() {
    spawn(&worker, thisTid);

    // This line will block until the expected message is received.
    receive (
        (string message) {
            writeln("Received the message: ", text);
        },
    )
}
```

What I am needing is to merely receive data if there is some.  Something like this:

```
void main() {
    Queue!string queue// custom `Queue` type based on DList

    spawn(&worker, queue);

    while (true) {
        // Go through any messages (while consuming `queue`)
        for (string message; queue) {
            writeln("Received a message: ", text);
        }
        // Do other stuff
    }
}
```

I have tried using `shared` variables (https://tour.dlang.org/tour/en/multithreading/synchronization-sharing) but DMD is complaining that "Aliases to mutable thread-local data not allowed." or some other errors, depending.

How would this be done in D?  Or, is there a way to use messages to do this kind of communication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have gotten the answer I need.

Simply put, use `core.thread` rather than `std.concurrency`.  `std.concurrency` manages messages for you and does not allow you to manage it yourself.  `core.thread` is what `std.concurrency` uses internally.

The longer answer, here is how I fully implemented it.

I have created a `Queue` type that is based on an [Singly Linked List](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list) but maintains a pointer of the last element.  The `Queue` also uses standard component inputRange and outputRange (or at least I think it does) per Walter Brights vision (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cQkBOCo8UrE).
The `Queue` is also built to allow one thread to write and another to read with very little mutexing internally so it should be fast. 

The Queue I shared here https://pastebin.com/ddyPpLrp

A simple implementation to have a second thread read input:

```
Queue!string inputQueue = new Queue!string;
ThreadInput threadInput = new ThreadInput(inputQueue);
threadInput.start;

while (true) {
    foreach (string value; inputQueue) {
        writeln(value);
    }
}
```

`ThreadInput` being defined as thus:

```
class ThreadInput : Thread {
    private Queue!string queue;

    this(Queue!string queue) {
        super(&run);
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    private void run() {
        while (true) {
            queue.put(readln);
        }
    }
}
```

The code https://pastebin.com/w5jwRVrL
The `Queue` again https://pastebin.com/ddyPpLrp

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the specific question but ti does clear up what I think is a misunderstanding of the message passing api...

just call `receiveTimeout` instead of plain `receive`

http://dpldocs.info/experimental-docs/std.concurrency.receiveTimeout.html

Comment: No this isn't really what I need but I did miss `receiveTimeout` I am not sure how.  If I cannot get anything else working I will probably be able to use `receiveTimeout` to do what I need.

Comment: Giving receiveTimout a negative value like -1 will do what you want. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31624806/2026276

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
shared class Queue(T) {

    private T[] queue;

    synchronized void opOpAssign(string op)(T object) if(op == "~") {
        queue ~= object;
    }

    synchronized size_t length(){
        return queue.length;
    }

    synchronized T pop(){
        assert(queue.length, "Please check queue length, is 0");
        auto first = queue[0];
        queue = queue[1..$];
        return first;
    }

    synchronized shared(T[]) consume(){
        auto copy = queue;
        queue = [];
        return copy;
    }

}
```